Deja Dup restore backup fail with unkonow error
I back up all my files from my last Ubuntu 22.04 OS to my external SSD. I installed the new Ubuntu 22.04 and when I try to restore my files with Deja Dup it fails with an unknown error. In terminal, I got this log
(org.gnome.DejaDup:8704): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:06:46.021: g_date_time_new_from_iso8601: assertion 'text != NULL' failed

I got 1846 zip files containing 98GB, all with similar names. like this one:

duplicity-full.20240403T095423Z.vol1.difftar.gz

I need these files.

No the files were in the same time zone as now.
I try to get my file list with this piece of code:
duplicity list-current-files "file://PasteLocationHere" > backuplist.txt
and in the terminal, it shows me the list of files until it snaps. I have a lot of files like npm packages and atom extensions that I don't need at all... I think I got too many files and it just breaks. Maybe if I can delete somehow the files I don't need with duplicity? I will try other ways will write here.

You may have to ask the Deja Dup developers.

thank you i will do that
